# What should the off diagonal block be like to ensure positive semi-definiteness?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite, block-matrices

Suppose we have a complex block matrix, with $2 \times 2$ blocks:

$$M = \begin{bmatrix} A && B \\ B^T && C \end{bmatrix},$$

where

$$B = \begin{bmatrix} x && 0 \\ 0 && -x \end{bmatrix},$$

With $x$ being a real number. If $A \ge 0$ and $C \ge 0$ (they are both Hermitian), is it possible to find a necessary and sufficient condition on $x$ to make sure that the matrix $M$ is positive semidefinite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When at least one of $A$ or $C$ is singular, clearly $M$ is PSD if and only if $x=0$.

When $A$ and $C$ are positive definite, $M$ is congruent to $(A-BC^{-1}B)\oplus C$. Let $D=\operatorname{diag}(1,-1)$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
M\succeq0
&\Leftrightarrow A\succeq BC^{-1}B\\
&\Leftrightarrow I\succeq A^{-1/2}BC^{-1}BA^{-1/2}\\
&\Leftrightarrow \rho(A^{-1/2}BC^{-1}BA^{-1/2})\le1\\
&\Leftrightarrow \rho(A^{-1}BC^{-1}B)\le1\\
&\Leftrightarrow x^2\le\frac{1}{\rho(A^{-1}DC^{-1}D)}.\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Can you give a reference about the cyclic invariance of the spectral radius ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I am not aware of any reference. Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis* has probably mentioned this but I am too lazy to check. I vaguely remember that the book has a lemma in the form of $A\succeq B\Leftrightarrow \rho(A^{-1}B)\le1$ whenever $A\succ0$ and $B\succeq0$. Anyway, I think most authors regard $\rho(XY)=\rho(YX)$ as a direct consequence of the fact that $XY$ and $YX$ have the same spectrum when $X$ and $Y$ are square matrices, and so they don't need to prove it specifically.

Comment: Thanks for answering. You are right, I didn't realize that it's a direct consequence of the result you mention in your last sentence.

Comment: Why is this true: When at least one of $A$ or $C$ is singular, clearly $M$ is PSD if and only if $x=0$?

Comment: @Bard In general, for a Hermitian matrix $\pmatrix{A&B\\ B^\ast&C}$ to be PSD, we must have $\operatorname{range}(B)\subseteq\operatorname{range}(A)$ and $\operatorname{range}(B^\ast)\subseteq\operatorname{range}(C)$. E.g. suppose the contrary that $Bv\not\in\operatorname{range}(A)$. Since $A$ is Hermitian, $\ker(A)=\operatorname{range}(A)^\perp$. Therefore $Bv=u+w$ for some nonzero vector $u\in\ker(A)$ and for some $w\perp u$. But then when $t>0$ is large, we will have
$$\pmatrix{-tu^\ast&v^\ast}M\pmatrix{-tu\\ v}=-2t\operatorname{Re}(u^\ast Bv)+v^\ast Cv=-2t\|u\|^2+v^\ast Cv<0.$$